# Strange Characters In A Char

Tags: c++

So heres what the program is supposed to do: Restrict applications from opening on a mac by typing restrict . It is supposed to allow access to the application by typing restrict  again using the same name as before.

What the program is doing instead: Restricting the application is working fine. But when I type restrict  again, it comes up with the following output:

```
CandyBar
\277_\377CandyBar
\277_\377Restricting application
chmod: /Applications/CandyBar
\277_\377.app: No such file or directory
chown: /Applications/CandyBar
\277_\377.app: No such file or directory
chmod: /Applications/CandyBar
\277_\377.app: No such file or directory
```

As you can see it adds the characters `\277_\377` at the end of the string. Here is my source code:

```
for (int i = 0; strlen(argument) + 14 >= i; i++) {
    argument[i] = '\0';
}
cout << argument;

getArguments();
argument[strlen(argument) - 1] = '\0';
cout << argument;
string application(argument);
cout << application;
if (!restrictedApplication[application]) {
    restrictedApplication[application] = false;
}
if (restrictedApplication[application] == false) {
    cout << "Restricting application\n";
    restrictedApplication[application] = true;
    string fullCommand =
        "chmod -x '/Applications/" + application + ".app';" + 
        "chown root '/Applications/" + application + ".app';" + 
        "chmod 000 '/Applications/" + application + ".app'";
    char fullCommandChar[256];
    for (int i = 0; fullCommand[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        fullCommandChar[i] = fullCommand[i];
    }
    system(fullCommandChar);
}
else {
    cout << "Restoring application\n";
    restrictedApplication[application] = false;
    string fullCommand =
        "chmod +x '/Applications/" + application + ".app';" +
        "chown jamespickering '/Applications/" + application + ".app';" +
        "chmod 777 '/Applications/" + application + ".app'";
    char fullCommandChar[256];
    for (int i = 0; fullCommand[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        fullCommandChar[i] = fullCommand[i];
    }
    system(fullCommandChar);
}
```

Comment: What does `getArguments()` do? How is `argument` declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because it's looking for the `\0` character at the end of the string but it's never receiving it.

I haven't looked deep in your code yet but i see that you are trying to do that here.

```
argument[strlen(argument) - 1] = '\0';
```

I'll edit my post when I find where the `\0` is going haywire because that's what produces that weird

`\277_\377` output.

---

edit:

```
for (int i = 0; strlen(argument) + 14 >= i; i++) {
     argument[i] = '\0';
}
```

What are you trying to do with this part of code?

This is essentially, looping through and adding `\0` from `index 0` to the `length of the string plus 14` to argument. This should going passed argument's array size, correct? Can someone explain how this can even show an output?

Comment: Array bounds are not checked at compile time, there's no reason for it not to compile.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths excuse me i meant to say produce an output.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the definition of `argument`, but this wouldn't necessarily make it go out of bounds. `strlen()` returns the length of the string, not the length of the array. For instance, if he declared `char argument[100] = "not much";` then it would be fine.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Agreed. haha for instance he declared `char fullCommandChar[256];` Thanks for clearing that up either way that loop seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Okay the +14 was added to try to get rid of the extraneous 14 characters mentioned at the top. @PaulGriffiths command getArguments() gets the argument after restrict and stores it in the char array argument

Comment: @progenhard I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about the argument array. See the above comment.

Comment: @InsertNameHere: But you still `cout << argument;` before you call `getArguments();`

Comment: Oh @PaulGriffiths I was makng sure that arguments was completely clear before i store stuff to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
for (int i = 0; strlen(argument) + 14 >= i; i++) {
    argument[i] = '\0';
}
cout << argument;
```

you set the first element of `argument` to `0`, and then try to output it. What exactly are you trying to output? You empty the string when you do that.